# Expo Android over scroll glitch

Tags: android, react-native, expo, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have an annoying glitch when using my expo app on Android. When I use `ScrollView` with `overScrollMode` set to `'always'` or `'auto'` and I scroll bit fast on beginning, I can reach bit further then where is actual beginning. Then when I scroll just I bit down, then it immediately snap back where ir should originally stops.
And there's even more glitches when using horizontal scroll. When I do the same thing it sometimes scroll to oposite direction and do some wired stuff. It is really hard to explain.
I was able to fix it all by setting `overScrollMode` to `'never'` but I really like the effect and want use it.
Does anyone else have had the same issue and how should I fix it?